# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdminsService

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I get this error message when i import another module service in DoctorsService:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdminsService (?). Please make
> sure that the argument AdminsRepository at index [0] is available in
> the DoctorsModule context.

I imported **AdminsService** in doctors.module in provider, but problem not solved.

**doctors.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModuleJwt],
  controllers: [DoctorsController],
  providers: [DoctorsService, AdminsService],
})
```

**admins.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModuleJwt, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AdminsRepository])],
  controllers: [AdminsController],
  providers: [AdminsService],
  exports: [AdminsService],
})
```

And finally this is my **doctors.service** and here the error occurs:

```
@Injectable()
export class DoctorsService {
  constructor(private adminsService: AdminsService) {}

  async create(createDoctorDto: CreateDoctorDto): Promise<DoctorPayload> {
    const { user_id, name, avatar, bio } = createDoctorDto;

    await this.adminsService.findOne(user_id);

    const doctor = new Doctor();
    doctor.user_id = user_id;
    doctor.name = name;
    doctor.avatar = avatar;
    doctor.bio = bio;

    try {
      return await doctor.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

and my **admins.service**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(AdminsRepository)
    private adminsRepository: AdminsRepository,
  ) {}

  async findOne(id: number): Promise<Admin> {
    const admin = await this.adminsRepository.findById(id);

    if (!admin) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    delete admin.password;
    return admin;
  }
}
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdminsService` is exported from `AdminsModule`. To use it inside another module, you need to import it.

```
// doctors.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModuleJwt, AdminsModule], // Add AdminsModule here
  controllers: [DoctorsController],
  providers: [DoctorsService], // Remove AdminsService here
})
```

Note that DoctorsModule should not provide `AdminsService`, as its already provided by `AdminsModule`.